# java.lang.StackOverflowError is showing but I can't figure it out why

Tags: java, stack-overflow

So I have two classes, one extends the main class, I'm working with swing and when I want to setTitle or other things in main class i get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at javaapplication5.PrviProzor.setTitle(PrviProzor.java:166)
    at javaapplication5.Timer1.main(Timer1.java:15)
```

This is the code in Main class:

```
int opcija = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choose option", "Option dialog", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new String[] {"Settings", "Close"}, null);
        if(opcija==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

            PrviProzor prviProzor = new PrviProzor();
            prviProzor.setTitle("Timer");
            prviProzor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            prviProzor.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            prviProzor.setVisible(true);

        }
        if(opcija==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
            exit();
        }
```

and the program want's me to put the setTitle,setDefaultCloseOperation..and the rest methods in my second class and these are the methods that are default:

```
void setTitle(String timer) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    void setDefaultCloseOperation(int EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    void setLocationRelativeTo(Object object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    void setVisible(boolean b) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


And the program still doesn't work, I still get the java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. What should I do?
```

Comment: It looks like your class `PrviProzor` does not extends from `JFrame`.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Let `PrviProzor` extends from `JFrame`. It looks like it doesn't. These methods you are trying to call are from that class.

Comment: It does extend, but still doesn't work

Comment: Did you remove the outgenerated methods you posted? If not they will still be used and not the ones from JFrame.

Answer (score -2):

How about implementing the actual methods?

Edit:
Okay, to be a bit more helpful in case someone still has not understood it.

```
void setTitle(String timer) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
```

Assuming you autogenerated your class and this is the implementation in your PrviProzor class, then you need to implement it for **real** . Else I can only say, your code is working as expected.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do that properly since my code is in two classes, but can't still find the right way to do it.

Comment: You might as well as post the content of PrviProzor as it is currently, so we do not need to guess.